what would be an alternative for Spin Launch?
I've seen Spin Launch several times, a system where payload/rocket is spun up to a certain velocity in a vacuum and then "thrown" into the exosphere or space. I found this concept of "throwing" rockets quite interesting and potentially effective. I can't help but wonder if there's any other such efficient way to "throw" rockets such as a slingshot or rail gun set up?

The list of non-rocket space launch systems is very long including Mass drivers, orbital rings, rotovators, lofstrom loops, space fountains, space towers, tethered rings, dark sky station, space Elevator, beam-powered ships and so much more.
However, since you are asking about methods of "throwing" things into space, one interesting concept is the rotating skyhook. Essentially, it’s a spinning tether or cable in orbit that can fling spacecrafts to higher velocities.

You can picture it like a car wheel on the road: the part of the wheel touching the ground isn’t moving relative to the ground, while the top of the wheel is moving at twice the speed of the car itself. Similarly, if a spacecraft docks at the bottom of the rotating skyhook, it can be flung, gaining additional speed.
To ensure the spacecraft doesn’t destabilize the skyhook by causing it to rotate around its center of mass, the skyhook's center of mass has to be positioned on the opposite end of the cable. This can be achieved by attaching a counterweight, like a space station, a small asteroid, or another celestial object.
In space the skyhook would transfer its rotational energy into kinetic energy and accelerate the spacecraft, but after repeated use, the skyhook’s rotation would slow down. To maintain its spin, incoming spacecraft can transfer their kinetic energy back to the skyhook. This is like an orbital battery. Instead of wasting all your kinetic energy into thermal energy during reentry, it can be re-used for the next spacecraft taking off.

Structures that large freak me out to be honest. A 400-kilometer structure spinning at Mach-who-knows-what and rolling around the planet... I can't imagine who would pay to build that. But +1 for mentioning it!

Sadly, energy conservation laws still apply. So with every launch, the skyhook transfers some of it's own energy onto the playload. This energy has to be replenished somehow. Either by using the skyhook to deorbit the same mass as is puts into orbit or by other means... there is no such thing as a free meal in physics.

@TrySCE2AUX I didn’t say it was free. Incoming spacecrafts use a skyhook to decelerate. They dock at the "top" of the wheel and are released at the "bottom". The skyhook gains rotational energy and the spacecraft losses its kinetic energy. Nothing here is free. It is just a conversion.

Right, but that only works if your lift and drop masses are balanced, which is almost never going to be the case. The thing we always need is more lift capacity. In virtually any scenario, we're not primarily importing space-stuff to Earth, we're trying to build infrastructure in space. Which means we're gonna have to use some form of propulsion to respin the wheel. It may be possible to counteract the losses with low-impulse/high-efficiency drives, but we're going to have to counteract the losses one way or another.

@DarthPseudonym that’s why I called it an orbital battery. It is a good thing to have when you have regular travel from one place to another, like from Earth to Mars and back. If you are wanting to launch more stuff than is already in the system, you could use one of the other orbital launch systems I mentioned at the top

SpinLaunch isn't the first
The concept of Non-Rocket Spacelaunch is older than the concept of rockets, since Jules Verne's From the Earth to the Moon posited a massive cannon for the purpose in 1865, long before the idea of expendable rockets had first been discussed. That concept is now referred to as a "Space Gun", or sometimes a "Verne Cannon".
There are many, many concepts for various kinds of launch system that don't use an expendable rocket or replace the first stage rocket with a more exotic system, all with various problems and limitations.
Mass Drivers
Some of the more reasonable options are electromagnetic launchers of various types. The general term is "mass driver". Most mass driver concepts are basically a very long coilgun or linear motor track that accelerates a launch vehicle, either as a first stage or as a sort of magnetic Verne cannon that can loft an entirely unpowered vehicle into space.
The limitations of a mass driver are the length of the launch track and air resistance, which is why mass drivers are mostly discussed as a possibility for cheap lunar launches. On the moon, air isn't an issue, open space is ample, and the lower orbital velocity makes for a shorter track. Unmanned cargo could launch under accelerations of tens of G or more (but still far short of the many thousands of G that Spinlaunch cargo has to endure), while human launches could be possible with relatively moderate forces. A vehicle could launch into Lunar orbit with a small engine to circularize the orbit, or with good timing, a mass driver could throw a cargo pod into an earth-return orbit with no fuel usage at all.

Yes. There's quite a few other ideas out there:
Space Gun
This is what it sounds like, using some form of gun to launch things into space. Space Guns haven't sent anything to orbit yet, but in Project HARP a 410 mm (16 in) 100 caliber gun was used to fire a 180 kg (400 lb) projectile at 3,600 m/s (12,960 km/h; 8,050 mph), and it reached space, getting all the way up to 180 km (110 mi).
Ram Accelerator
The idea of this is that the projectile is fired using something else (such as the Space Gun idea from above) and then accelerated using jet engine-like systems. Ram Accelerators have not been used/tested very much.
Slingatron
According to Wikipedia:

In a slingatron, projectiles are accelerated along a rigid tube or track that typically has circular or spiral turns, or combinations of these geometries in two or three dimensions. A projectile is accelerated in the curved tube by propelling the entire tube in a small-amplitude circular motion of constant or increasing frequency without changing the orientation of the tube, i.e. the entire tube gyrates but does not spin. An everyday example of this motion is stirring a beverage by holding the container and moving it in small horizontal circles, causing the contents to spin, without spinning the container itself.


This gyration continually displaces the tube with a component along the direction of the centripetal force acting on the projectile, so that work is continually done on the projectile as it advances through the machine. The centripetal force experienced by the projectile is the accelerating force, and is proportional to the projectile mass and inversely proportional to the track's radius of curvature.


A slingatron is capable of much higher velocities than a similar circular launcher based on a rotating tether made of currently available materials (e.g. Dyneema). The maximum tip velocity of a rotating tether, irrespective of its absolute scale, is limited by the strength to weight ratio of its materials, as the tether must support its own mass under centripetal acceleration as well as that of the projectile. In the slingatron, the projectile's centrifugal force is instead reacted into a nonrotating structure which can be as massive as necessary.


There have been a number of proposals to accelerate payloads to a significant fraction of orbital velocity, or even orbital velocity, before launch.
Spinlaunch Can something like SpinLaunch actually work?
Railgun What technological hurdles prevent the development of a space gun?
Compressed spring Compressed helical spring powering an early stage of rocket
Whip Alternative small mass payload transportation from the moon to L5 besides rail gun and mass driver?
Space Gun  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_gun
None of these strategies will achieve orbital speed from the surface of the Earth due to the high launch speed and Earth’s dense atmosphere.
Ground-launching an object into orbit means it needs to be launched at orbital speed, plus some. At these speeds, heating from air friction would be like re-entry, but worse since the ground level atmosphere is thicker. The launch vehicle would burn up, break up, slow down, or all three at once.
Spin Launch (and some other strategies) launch at suborbital speed to avoid burning up, then accelerate in the upper atmosphere with rockets or ram jets
The approach of using a gun to launch a rocket projectile has been pursued by the military.
Some artillery shells are gun-launched but rocket assisted, known as rocket-assisted projectiles (RAP). However, these have a maximum range of 60 km.
The US Navy developed (but did not deploy) an Extended Range Guided Munition which was a precision guided rocket-assisted 5-inch shell. It reached a maximum speed of 3000 km/hr and an altitude of 24km, then glided to the target with a range of 110 km.
Its interesting that Spinlaunch uses a similar strategy to the Navy, but the initial acceleration of the rocket/shell is almost twice as fast: 7500km/hr
It is often said “Getting to orbit isn’t about going up. It is about going sideways …fast.”
Perhaps that should read, “… Getting to orbit isn’t about going sideways fast…It’s about going up slowly, then going sideways fast.”
The strategy of “Go up fast, … then turn sideways” hasn’t caught on.
